# Do I have to do StringIO.close()?

Tags: python, stringio

Some code:

```
import cStringIO

def f():
    buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
    buffer.write('something')
    return buffer.getvalue()
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO.close) says:

> `StringIO.close()`: Free the memory buffer. Attempting to do further
>   operations with a closed StringIO object will raise a ValueError.

Do I have to do `buffer.close()`, or it will happen automatically when buffer goes out of scope and is garbage collected?

**UPDATE:**

I did a test:

```
import StringIO, weakref

def handler(ref):
    print 'Buffer died!'

def f():
    buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    ref = weakref.ref(buffer, handler)
    buffer.write('something')
    return buffer.getvalue()

print 'before f()'
f()
print 'after f()'
```

Result:

```
vic@wic:~/projects$ python test.py 
before f()
Buffer died!
after f()
vic@wic:~/projects$
```

Comment: why not print f() instead of just a naked f()?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally it's still better to call `close()` or use the `with` statement, because there may be some unexpected behaviour in special circumstances. For example, the expat-`IncrementalParser` seems to expect a file to be closed, or it won't return the last tidbit of parsed xml until a timeout occurs in some rare circumstances.

But for the `with`-statement, which handles the closing for you, you have to use the `StringIO` class from the `io`-Modules, as stated in the comment of Ivc.

This was a major headache in some legacy sax-parser script we solved by closing the StringIO manually.

The "out-of-scope" close didn't work. It just waited for the timeout-limit.

Comment: Except note that StringIO and cStringIO in Py2 don't implement the context manager protocol - so, to use it in a `with` statement you need to do `with contextlib.closing(StringIO()) as buffer:`. Py3's `io.StringIO`, on the other hand, *can* be used in a `with` statement directly.

Comment: `io.StringIO` does implement the context-manager protocol, but not prior 2.6 see: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/io.htmlhighlight=io.stringio#io.IOBase`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that the `io` module existed that far back. Thanks for the pointer. However, it remains that the `StringIO.StringIO` and `cStringIO.StringIO` modules used in the OP don't. I'm actually slightly surprised they're not marked as deprecated in 2.6/2.7, and that there isn't even the usual note in the 2.7 docs saying "these don't exist anymore in 3.x".

Comment: You're right and quite frankly i didn't really pay attention to the fact, the OP didn't use the io Module! Thanks for pointing that out! ;-)

Answer (score 23):

From the source:

```
class StringIO:
    ...
    def close(self):
        """Free the memory buffer.
        """
        if not self.closed:
            self.closed = True
            del self.buf, self.pos
```

So `StringIO.close` just frees the memory buffer deleting references to `StringIO.buf` and `StringIO.pos`. But if `self` is garbage collected, its attributes will also be garbage collected, having the same effect as `StringIO.close`.

Answer (score 13):

`StringIO.close()` is merely a convenience for routines that take a file-like and eventually attempt to close them. There is no need to do so yourself.

Comment: It's not a convenience, rather a necessity. Without it code that closes file-like object would break.

Comment: @Maxim: It's a necessity for that code. It's a convenience for the client.

Answer (score 3):

I wound up using a `try` block to handle it.

```
import cStringIO

def f():
    buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
    try:
        buffer.write('something')
        return buffer.getvalue()
    finally:
        buffer.close()
```

Comment: Or, use a `with closing()` from `contextlib.closing`.