# Python - how to save uu.encode() output to a variable

Tags: python, encoding

I want to encode a file using [uu.encode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uu.html) method and use the encoded text in the script. For this I have to write that output to a file, by default uu.encode(input_file, output_file) requires the output file name so that it can write the encoded text to that file, then read the file to store in a variable.

But I don't want to do this and store the encoded text directly into a variable. Is it possible?

Here is the typical usage of uu.encode:

```
import uu
uu.encode("myfile.exe", "encoded_exe.txt")
```

I tried some stupid moves like this, which took me nowhere.

```
>>> data = uu.encode("M8510-8681-2015-09-29-220157.flv", sys.stdout.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: File not open for reading
>>>
```

This is not a must-requirement for me, but want to learn a thing or two using this opportunity.

Comment: Have you tried using a temporary file? https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to create a file-like object as described in the `uu` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uu.html).

```
import uu

uu.encode("Bar.txt", "Hello.txt")

import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()
uu.encode("Bar.txt", output)
print output.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a python tempfile. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html for something more sophisticated. But if you really want to avoid this, you could also try looking at this: [virtual file processing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550127/virtual-file-processing-in-python) for several examples of StringIO and ByteIO.