# Open Image from requests.response.content

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library, bytesio

What I am trying to do is quite simple when dealing with a local file, but the problem comes when I try to do it with a remote URL.

Basically, I am trying to create a PIL image object from a file extracted from a URL. Of course, I could always fetch the URL and store it in a temporary file, then open it in an image object, but that seems very inefficient.

Here is what I have:

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

So the Code is not returning the image if anyone knows.

Comment: Read [Downloading image with PIL and requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37752185/7414759)

Comment: You haven't set a value for `url`.

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: On exit there is no error, except that the image does not appear in the console

Comment: It works fine if you set `url`. Why do expect the image to appear? You haven't called anything to show it.