# How to filter sys.stdout?

Tags: python, newline, google-api-client

I'd like to filter the content print to `sys.stdout`. Specifically, I'd like to replace crlf with lf. I don't want to call external program. Is there a way to do so within python?

```
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(sys.stdout, request)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you are providing a file-like object for the class to write data.

You could use a child class that behaves the way you want OR let it write to a file and then process it OR use a [virtual file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)

Related: [How to do virtual file processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550127/how-to-do-virtual-file-processing)