# How to fix None Exception iterating requests! issue

Tags: python, speech-recognition, dialogflow-es, grpc, pepper

I'm fresh in speech recognition topic

I'm working on project in which I can find some usecases for Pepper bot in the workspace. Playing with Pepper we figured out some issues with it's speech recognition ability. I've found that we can try to connect it with external engines for that and I picked up DialogFlow from GCP.
Also because I've found some integrations with this service.
I've used code from this [project](https://medium.com/@pwc.emtech.eu/pepper-integration-with-dialogflow-1d7f1582da1a)

```
import traceback
from naoqi import qi


# [START dialogflow_detect_intent_streaming]
def detect_intent_stream(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                         language_code,ip):

    """Returns the result of detect intent with streaming audio as input.
    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""
    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    # Note: hard coding audio_encoding and sample_rate_hertz for simplicity.
    audio_encoding = dialogflow.enums.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16
    sample_rate_hertz = 44100

    session_path = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session_path))

    def request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path):
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)
        # The first request contains the configuration.
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=session_path, query_input=query_input)
        # Here we are reading small chunks of audio data from a local
        # audio file.  In practice these chunks should come from
        # an audio input device.
        try:
            with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
                while True:
                    chunk = audio_file.read(4096)
                    print(chunk)
                    if not chunk:
                        break
        except:
                traceback.print_exc()

                # The later requests contains audio data.

                yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)


    audio_config = dialogflow.types.InputAudioConfig(audio_encoding=audio_encoding, language_code=language_code, sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate_hertz)

    requests = request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path)
    responses = session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)


    print('=' * 20)
    for response in responses:
        print('Intermediate transcript: "{}".'.format(response.recognition_result.transcript))

    # Note: The result from the last response is the final transcript along
    # with the detected content.
    query_result = response.query_result
    session = qi.Session()
    try:
        tts = session.service("ALTextToSpeech")
        tts.say(query_result.fulfillment_text)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise Exception("session.connect failed.")
    finally:
        session.close()
    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(query_result.query_text))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
        query_result.intent.display_name,
        query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
        query_result.fulfillment_text))
# [END dialogflow_detect_intent_streaming]
```

EDITED: (adding pepper_recorder.py code)
Code below is taking any sound from Pepper and send only with desire peak to dialog flow detect_intent_stream

```
import StringIO
from Queue import Queue
from naoqi import ALModule, ALProxy
import numpy as np
import time
import logging
import uuid
import traceback



from detect_intent_stream import detect_intent_stream

LISTEN_RETRIES = 10
DIALOG_FLOW_GCP_PROJECT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

class SoundProcessingModule(ALModule):
    def __init__( self, name, ip, stop_recognition):
        try:
            ALModule.__init__( self, name );
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(str(e))
            pass
        print("connected")
        self.ip = ip
        self.BIND_PYTHON( name, "processRemote")
        self.ALAudioDevice = ALProxy("ALAudioDevice", self.ip, 9559)
        self.framesCount=0
        self.count = LISTEN_RETRIES
        self.recordingInProgress = False
        self.stopRecognition = stop_recognition
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        self.previous_sound_data = None

    def startProcessing(self):
        """init sound processing, set microphone and stream rate"""
        print("startProcessing")
        self.ALAudioDevice.setClientPreferences(self.getName(), 16000, 4, 0)
        self.ALAudioDevice.subscribe(self.getName())
        while not self.stopRecognition.is_set():
            time.sleep(1)

        self.ALAudioDevice.unsubscribe(self.getName())

    def processRemote(self, nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel, timeStamp, inputBuffer):
        
        """audio stream callback method with simple silence detection"""
        self.framesCount = self.framesCount + 1
        sound_data_interlaced = np.fromstring(str(inputBuffer), dtype=np.int16)
        sound_data = np.reshape(sound_data_interlaced, (nbOfChannels, nbOfSamplesByChannel), 'F')
        peak_value = np.max(sound_data)
        # detect sound
        if peak_value > 10000:
            print("Peak:", peak_value)
            self.count = LISTEN_RETRIES
            if not self.recordingInProgress:
                self.startRecording(self.previous_sound_data)
        # if there is no sound for a few seconds we end the current recording and start audio processing
        if self.count <= 0 and self.recordingInProgress:
            self.stopRecording()
        # if recording is in progress we save the sound to an in-memory file
        if self.recordingInProgress:
            self.count -= 1
            self.previous_data = sound_data
            self.procssingQueue.put(sound_data[0].tostring())
            self.outfile.write(sound_data[0].tostring())



    def startRecording(self, previous_sound_data):
        """init a in memory file object and save the last raw sound buffer to it."""
        self.outfile = StringIO.StringIO()
        self.procssingQueue = Queue()
        self.recordingInProgress = True
        if not previous_sound_data is None:
            self.procssingQueue.put(previous_sound_data[0].tostring())
            self.outfile.write(previous_sound_data[0].tostring())


        print("start recording")

    def stopRecording(self):
        """saves the recording to memory"""
        print("stopped recording")
        self.previous_sound_data = None
        self.outfile.seek(0)
        try:
            detect_intent_stream(DIALOG_FLOW_GCP_PROJECT_ID, self.uuid,
                                 self.outfile, "en-US", self.ip)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        self.recordingInProgress = False
```

I'm connected to the robot and it is listening but each time it starts to record I have something like this in console

('Peak:', 14023)

start recording

stopped recording

Session path: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

====================

And then error...

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
>   File
> "C:\Users\marwloda\PycharmProjects\Pepper\scripts\pepper_recorder.py",
> line 83, in stopRecording    self.outfile, "en-US", self.ip)   File
> "C:\Users\marwloda\PycharmProjects\Pepper\scripts\detect_intent_stream.py",
> line 76, in detect_intent_stream    for response in responses:   File
> "C:\Users\marwloda\PycharmProjects\Pepper\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py",
> line 81, in next
>     six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)   File "C:\Users\marwloda\PycharmProjects\Pepper\venv\lib\site-packages\six.py",
> line 737, in raise_from
>     raise value Unknown: None Exception iterating requests!
```

If like audio_file recorded from robot was empty.
But I've done some prints of speech reco data and produce some raw unreadable string

To proof that I have some connection to API - when I open GCP console API & services I see this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xaP9.jpg)

What might cause this error?
Where should I look for causes ?

Comment: HI Marek please also provide the pepper_recorder.py so we can try to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently you are passing `StringIO` to `detect_intent_stream` as `audio_file_path` where at:

```
with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
```

you try to open the `StringIO` as a File

But:

> A StringIO instance is an open file already. The open command, on the
>   other hand, only takes filenames, to return an open file. A StringIO
>   instance is not suitable as a filename. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892623/stringio-and-compatibility-with-with-statement-context-manager)

So the `request_generator` function in `detect_intent_stream` needs to look like:

```
def request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path):
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)        
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=session_path, query_input=query_input)        
        while True:
            chunk = audio_file_path.read(4096)
            if not chunk:
                break
            yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            input_audio=chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it ASAP as I will get my hands on Pepper. Yesterday I was thinking about it at the end of work by checking if opening StringIO has making any sense but didn't have time to change the code.

Comment: Hi, It worked and I hitting dialogflow without errors but... response.recognition_result.transcript is not transcribing like no speech was recorded :/
EDIT: I simply change hertz rate and it starts to produce responses THANKS A LOT !

Answer (score 0):

Hi there might be an issue with your audio file or the network connection.
Have you tried to send a simple text or a prerecorded wav file as input to dialogflow?

This script works well on my pepper: (my wav file is Mono, 44100Hz, 32Bit)

```
import os
import time
import sys
import uuid
import google

def printResponse(response):
    print('=' * 20)
    print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text.encode('utf-8')))
    print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})'.format(
        response.query_result.intent.display_name.encode('utf-8'),
        response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
    print('Fulfillment text: {}'.format(
        response.query_result.fulfillment_text.encode('utf-8')))


def detect_intent_audio(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                        language_code, sample_rate_hertz):

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    # Note: hard coding audio_encoding and sample_rate_hertz for simplicity.
    audio_encoding = dialogflow.enums.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
        input_audio = audio_file.read()

    audio_config = dialogflow.types.InputAudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=audio_encoding, language_code=language_code,
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate_hertz)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

    response = session_client.detect_intent(
        session=session, query_input=query_input,
        input_audio=input_audio)

    printResponse(response)

def detect_intent_stream(project_id, session_id, audio_file_path,
                         language_code, sample_rate_hertz):

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    # Note: hard coding audio_encoding and sample_rate_hertz for simplicity.
    audio_encoding = dialogflow.enums.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16

    session_path = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    def request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path):
        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

        # The first request contains the configuration.
        yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=session_path, query_input=query_input)

        # Here we are reading small chunks of audio data from a local
        # audio file.  In practice these chunks should come from
        # an audio input device.
        with open(audio_file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
            while True:

                chunk = audio_file.read(4096)

                if not chunk:
                    break
                # The later requests contains audio data.
                yield dialogflow.types.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
                    input_audio=chunk)

    audio_config = dialogflow.types.InputAudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=audio_encoding, language_code=language_code,
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate_hertz)

    requests = request_generator(audio_config, audio_file_path)
    responses = session_client.streaming_detect_intent(requests)

    print('=' * 20)
    for response in responses:
        print('Intermediate transcript: "{}".'.format(
                response.recognition_result.transcript.encode('utf-8')))

    # Note: The result from the last response is the final transcript along
    # with the detected content.

    printResponse(response)

def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        printResponse(response)


project_id = 'my_project_id'
session_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
language_code = 'de'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.path.join('/home/me/', 'xyz.json')
wav_path = os.path.join('/home/me/', 'audio.wav')

try:
    print ("detect_intent_texts:")
    detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, ["Hallo"], language_code)
    print('=' * 20)   

    print ("detect_intent_audio:")
    detect_intent_audio(project_id, session_id, wav_path, language_code, 44100)
    print('=' * 20)

    print ("detect_intent_stream:")
    detect_intent_stream(project_id, session_id, wav_path, language_code, 44100)
    print('=' * 20)
except google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable:
        print("503 Connect Failed")
```

Comment: I was able to test detect_intent_text function and it works so connection is ok. I do not have wav file.
I'm storring Recording from Pepper in memory as StringIO.StringIO instance and I would preffer to stay that way

Comment: you can stick to your preferred implementation this is just for testing...

Comment: But still I don't know why stringIO is not consumed by streaming_detect_intent. In consol I can se that 100% hits of Sessions.StreamingDetectIntent is ending with error.

Comment: But you will know if calling streaming_detect_intent in general works. Then you can dive deeper into other factors. 
You need to add more code to your question, The code you posted does not contain any StringIO.

Comment: Hi Marek, since you are new to Stackoverflow. I kindly ask you to get used to add code and details to your question. This will be clearer and helpful for future visitors.

Comment: Its also helpful to post all the relevant code, not only snippets that can't be used to reproduce the problem. You mentioned the project you used for orientation but you might have done something differently that's why you might have the issue and you need to add code to your question.

Comment: Hi, @TVK thank you for your asking. you are right there might be problem with it.