# How to simulate a filename for a legacy function to provide data that is already in memory?

Tags: python

I want to use a legacy function that receives a filename as an argument. The function will make some processing after opening that file.

```
def legacy_f(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        # some processing
```

But I want the processing to happen in some data that is loaded in some variable already, not in a file. Saving the data to a file first is not a solution due to performance. Is there a way to "fool" the legacy function to make it think it is opening a file?

My situation is exactly the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892623/stringio-and-compatibility-with-with-statement-context-manager), but the accepted answer there recommends the use of `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, which (I believe) does create a file in the disk. I can't afford that.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a bit hacky and probably not a good practice but it you could monkey patch the open function within a context manager. This wont replace open, but simply patch it with something else within that context manager. you can see if i call the function again but outside the context manager it reverts back to using the builtin open.

However this type of mocking is usually used for testing.

```py
from unittest import mock


def legacy_f(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            print(line, end="")
        print()

data = "this\nis\nsome\ndata"
filename = "somefile"

#patch the open call
with mock.patch('builtins.open', mock.mock_open(read_data=data)):
    legacy_f(filename)

#the patch only works in the conext manager, outside its the normal open
try:
    legacy_f(filename)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"file '{filename}' not found since we only patch in the context manager")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
this
is
some
data
file 'somefile' not found since we only patch in the context manager
```