# FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm getting this error when wrapping a soup element in a `str`.

I'm trying to parse a table with pandas. I'm getting the correct output but also this warning:

> "FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object

```py
def parse_html(box_scores):
    with open(box_scores) as f: 
        html = f.read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.theader")]
    return soup


def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs = {'id': 'line_score'})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols
    
    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]
    
    return line_score

def read_stats(soup, team, stat):
    df = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs={"id": f"box-{team}-game-{stat}"}, index_col=0)[0]
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
    return df
```

Comment: FYI: This warning is new policy for all the pandas `read` operations to no longer accept literal strings or bytes. See this [Git ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53767).

Answer (score 2):

Instead:

```
line_score = pd.read_html(str(soup), attrs = {'id': 'line_score'})[0]
```

Use `io.StringIO`:

```
from io import StringIO


def parse_html(box_scores):
    with open(box_scores) as f: 
        html = f.read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.theader")]
    return soup


def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(soup)), attrs = {'id': 'line_score'})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols
    
    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]
    
    return line_score

def read_stats(soup, team, stat):
    df = pd.read_html(StringIO(str(soup)), attrs={"id": f"box-{team}-game-{stat}"}, index_col=0)[0]
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
    return df
```

Comment: thank you so much. i was using it like StringIO(soup) and it didnt work. Now it works thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As the error description suggest you need to wrap it into `io.SringIO`. Here's how you'd do that:

```
def read_line_score(soup):
    line_score = pd.read_html(io.StringIO(str(soup)), attrs={'id': 'line_score'})[0]
    cols = list(line_score.columns)
    cols[0] = "team"
    cols[-1] = "total"
    line_score.columns = cols

    line_score = line_score[["team", "total"]]
    return line_score
```

Comment: Though arguable, I tend to use `io.StringIO` or `io.BytesIO` in a `with` context to explicitly free memory buffer. See [Do I have to do StringIO.close()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9718950/1422451)

Answer (score 0):

you can use io.StringIO to create a text buffer and then read the HTML content from it.

```
from io import StringIO

def parse_html(box_scores):
    with open(box_scores) as f: 
        html = f.read()
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.over_header")]
    [s.decompose() for s in soup.select("tr.theader")]
    
    # Use StringIO to wrap the HTML content
    html_buffer = StringIO(html)
    return BeautifulSoup(html_buffer, features="lxml")
```