# Passing literal html to read_html

Tags: python

I'm completely new to programming in Python and I am following an instructional YouTube video to learn about coding.

The YouTuber uses this code:

````
```python
 matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match = "Scores & Fixtures")
 ```
````

which looks outdated from the error message:

```
 FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match="Scores & Fixtures")
```

I typed the code as per the YouTube video and got the message above.
Could you tell what I should replace it by? Do I have to import `stringio`?

0

```
  T hanks so much

 Unfortunately I still have this error message...

 Would you mind helping further?   It looks like I've got some 
  importing to do I think ?
```

---

```
------ 
 -
  ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most
```

recent
call
last)
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-
packages\pandas\compat_optional.py:135, in
import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
134 try:
135     module = importlib.import_module(name)
136 except ImportError:

```
File 










  ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\
  __init__.py: 
90, in 
import_module(name, package)
 89         level += 1
 90 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1387, in _gcd_import(name, 
package, 
 level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1360, in _find_and_load(name, 
import_)
```

File :1310, in
*find_and_load_unlocked(name,
import*)

```
 File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:488, in 
_call_with_frames_removed(f, 
  *args, **kwds)

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1387, in _gcd_import(name, 
  package, 
   level)

 File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1360, in 
 _find_and_load(name, 
import_)

  File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1324, in 
 _find_and_load_unlocked(name,  
 import_)
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception 
   occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent 
call    
last)
Cell In[36], line 1
1 matches = pd.read_html(StringIO(data.text), match = "Scores & 
Fixtures")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
packages\pandas\io\html.py:1246, in read_html(io, match, flavor, 
header, 
index_col, skiprows, attrs, parse_dates, thousands, encoding, 
decimal, 
converters, na_values, keep_default_na, displayed_only, 
extract_links, 
dtype_backend, storage_options)
1230 if isinstance(io, str) and not any(
1231     [
1232         is_file_like(io),
(...)
1236     ]
1237 ):
1238     warnings.warn(
1239         "Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated
```

a  nd "
1240         "will be removed in a future version. To read from a
"
(...)
1243         stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
1244     )
1246 return _parse(
1247     flavor=flavor,
1248     io=io,
1249     match=match,
1250     header=header,
1251     index_col=index_col,
1252     skiprows=skiprows,
1253     parse_dates=parse_dates,
1254     thousands=thousands,
1255     attrs=attrs,
1256     encoding=encoding,
1257     decimal=decimal,
1258     converters=converters,
1259     na_values=na_values,
1260     keep_default_na=keep_default_na,
1261     displayed_only=displayed_only,
1262     extract_links=extract_links,
1263     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
1264     storage_options=storage_options,
1265 )

```
  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\io\html.py:977, in _parse(flavor, io, match, 
  attrs, 
   encoding, displayed_only, extract_links, storage_options, 
    **kwargs)
  975 retained = None
   976 for flav in flavor:
  977     parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
   978     p = parser(
  979         io,
  980         compiled_match,
  (...)
    985         storage_options,
   986     )
    988     try:

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
  packages\pandas\io\html.py:924, in _parser_dispatch(flavor)
 922     import_optional_dependency("bs4")
 923 else:
 924     import_optional_dependency("lxml.etree")
 925 return _valid_parsers[flavor]

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site- 
 packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py:138, in 
 import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
 136 except ImportError:
 137     if errors == "raise":
  138         raise ImportError(msg)
  139     return None   
141 # Handle submodules: if we have submodule, grab parent m 
  odule from 
 sys.modules

 ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'lxml'.  Use pip or 
   conda to 
  install lxml.
```

Comment: [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o) is a part of built-in `io` library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read\_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748143/futurewarning-passing-literal-html-to-read-html-is-deprecated-and-will-be-rem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a `FutureWarning`, you should still get the desired output. However, for the code to run in the future, yes; consider using `io.StringIO`:

```py
from io import StringIO

matches = pd.read_html(StringIO(data.text), match = "Scores & Fixtures")
```

See this thread, where this warning is discussed:
[FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748143/futurewarning-passing-literal-html-to-read-html-is-deprecated-and-will-be-rem?rq=2)